# jQuery - how to retrieve variable from POST?

Tags: jquery, json, post

I have following code:

```
$.post( '/map/getfile' ,data)
    .done(function(dataR) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(dataR);
        var sth = obj.number;
        })
    .always(function() {
        })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    alert( "finished" );
        });
```

I need the 'sth' variable in further place in code, but when I try

```
console.log(sth);
```

I have an error message like 'variable sth is undefined'.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sth` is defined in your `done` callback, and so will be local to it. Sounds like you're trying to access it outside of that scope.

Answer (score 1):

Call a function and pass in `sth`:

```
$.post( '/map/getfile' ,data)
    .done(function(dataR) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(dataR);
        var sth = obj.number;
        callback(sth);  // callback function that needs the sth variable
        })
    .always(function() {
        })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    alert( "finished" );
        });
```

Generally you would wrap the post in a function and pass the callback function in as a parameter so it can be changed easily:

```
 function getFilePost(callback) {
      // above post code
 }

 getFilePost(function(sth) { console.log(sth); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable `sth` in the scope where you need it or a higher up scope and in the `done` callback just set the value. However, since this is an `ajax` call, you won't have the value immediately available outside of the ajax call until the request is complete.

That should help you plan your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Call a function in `.done()` that will handle your results.

```
$.post( '/map/getfile' ,data)
    .done(function(dataR) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(dataR);
        displayResults(obj.number);
        })
    .always(function() {
        })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    alert( "finished" );
        });

var displayResults = function(sth) {
    alert(sth);
};
```

Comment: `console.log` will fire immediately and show nothing I'm guessing.

Comment: Oh sorry - you're right. But the variable will be defined as soon as post is done

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you need the "sth" variable inside always? Or maybe after the post itself? If so you could to this:

```
var sth;
$.post( '/map/getfile' ,data)
  .done(function(dataR) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(dataR);
    sth = obj.number;
    callback(sth);  // callback function that needs the sth variable
    })
  .always(function() {
    console.log(sth); // I expect "always" to be called by jQuery after "done"  
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
    alert( "finished" );
  });
console.log(sth);
```

If the post is inside a function and you need "sth" to be returned you have to use a callback or a promise.